# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.service.getDat().subscribe')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, testbed

I am working on an angular 4 Application, writing Unit Cases, I am facing below Problem.

**component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.data= JSON.parse(res._body);
      this.addFormControls();
    },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**component.spec.ts**

```
 describe('component', () => {

      let userRolesService: LayoutService;
      const modulesData = {
        'moduleName':'Info'
      }
      class MockUserRolesService {
        public getModulesData() {
            return modulesData;
        }
      }
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers:[ {provide: LayoutService, useClass: MockUserRolesService } ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        userRolesService = TestBed.get(LayoutService);

      });
      afterEach(() => {
        userRolesService = null;
       component = null;
     });


        it('should fetch module data', () => {

        userRolesService.getData().subscribe(
          result => {
          expect(result).toBeTruthy();
          }
      );
      });
    });
```

Updated the code for mock services file.Could you please help me some one to make it work. Used Mock service and test Bed Framework. Could you please some one help me..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Did you mock your service ? If not, did you mock your Http module ?

Comment: @trichetriche, I was import the http Module and Using Mock Services also.

Comment: Then post the code of your mocks please.

Comment: Can't be done, through real service call and real DB connection ?

Comment: That's not what unit tests are for. This is end to end testing you're talking about.

Comment: Post is edited, could you please check once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you tried to mock, but that's not how you mock a service.

I will use the `useValue` instead of the `useClass`, but you can adapt it if you want.

Your test is testing a subscription to an observable, and you return ... Nothing.

```
class MockUserRolesService {
  public getModulesData() {
    return modulesData;
  }
}
```

You're testing `getData` and I don't see it anywhere in your mock.

Here is how you mock your service.

```
const serviceMock = {
  provide: LayoutService,
  useValue: {
    getData: Observable.of(/* any value you want */)
  }
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers:[ {provide: LayoutService, useValue: serviceMock } ]
})
```

**EDIT** In unit testing, you test if your features (components, services) work as expected. let's take your `ngOnInit` function for instance :

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  this.data= JSON.parse(res._body);
  this.addFormControls();
}
```

Given how you wrote it, your tests should cover this cases :

- Does my component call `getData` on the service ?
- On success, does my component store the data returned by the service ?
- Does the console display the data ?
- Is the method `addFormControls` called ?

If you want to test that, you should create this mock :

```
useValue: {
  getData: Observable.of({
    '_body': 'my data'
  })
}
```

Now, you must make your test. 
Since you have an asynchronous call (with an Observable), then you should subscribe to the call, then call. Here is how it's done.

```
it('should call the getData function of the service and store the data', () => {
  // Spy on your service to see if it has been called, and let him process
  spyOn(component['service'], 'getData').and.callThrough();
  // Array notation avoid scope issues (if your variable is protected or private)
  component['service'].getData().subscribe(response => {
    expect(component['service'].getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Since you store the data in the data variable, check if it's equal to your mock value
    expect(component.data).toEqual('my data');
  });
});
```

If you want to test all cases :

```
it('should call the getData function of the service and store the data', () => {
  spyOn(component['service'], 'getData').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(component, 'addFormControls');
  spyOn(console, 'log');
  component['service'].getData().subscribe(response => {
    expect(component['service'].getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.data).toEqual('my data');
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(response);
    expect(component.addFormControls).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: can I assign simple value instead of  Observable.of , example 
`const serviceMock = {
  provide: LayoutService,
  useValue: {
    getData: "Simple"
  }
};`

Comment: No you can't. Your component uses the `subscribe` method of an Observable. If you don't provide an Observable (or a mock of an Observable, but it's easier to provide an Observable, trust me), your test will fail.

Comment: okay, thank you so much, could you please provide the one example of `Observable.of`, if you have any

Comment: `Observable.of(null)`. I told you, put whatever you want in your Observable. Do you know how unit tests actually work ?

Comment: Not Sure, i am very  new to this, That's I am hanging like this, thanks for your Help.

Comment: Okay, I edited my post to give you an example and a little explanation.

Comment: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.service.getData()') in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js (line 1643) Still same Issue

Comment: Still I am facing Same Issue  `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.service.getData()') in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js (line 1640)`, But What I observed is, Why here it is showing `this.service.getData()` that line was defined in component.ts file, not in component.spec.ts any idea, could you please help me out, I was used same way what you mentioned in answer

Comment: any help, still facing same issue.

Comment: `getData` comes from which service ?

Comment: `Layoutservice` but I was created instance in constructor `constructor(private service: LayoutService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue but inside a map

> undefined is not a constructor evaluating arr.uniorgs

so this:

```
this.arr.map(aux => aux.uniorgs)
```

i changed to:

```
this.arr.map(aux => aux['uniorgs'])
```